# How do I convince setuptools to use a temporary directory for requires packages from setup_require or tests_require?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

Inside the `setup.py` I have something like this:

```
setup_requires=['nose>=1.0'],
tests_require=[],
```

The problem is that when I run `./setup.py test` it will download and unpack these modules in the directory with `setup.py`.

How can I convince it to use a temporary directory for this, I do not want to polute the source control system with these, and I do not want to start adding lots and lots of exlude patters.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the source tree of your project you should probably make a script to delete all "dist" and "build" directories created by distutils at the end of the setup test.
Downloaded packages are usually *.egg folders in your source tree.

You are not polluting your distribution.

From setuptools documentation :

> **setup_requires** will NOT be automatically installed on the system where
>   the setup script is being run. They are simply downloaded to the setup
>   directory if they’re not locally available already. If you want them
>   to be installed, as well as being available when the setup script is
>   run, you should add them to install_requires and setup_requires.)

and

> **tests_require** If your project’s tests need one or more additional
>   packages besides those needed to install it, you can use this option
>   to specify them. It should be a string or list of strings specifying
>   what other distributions need to be present for the package’s tests to
>   run. When you run the test command, setuptools will attempt to obtain
>   these (even going so far as to download them using EasyInstall). Note
>   that these required projects will not be installed on the system where
>   the tests are run, but only downloaded to the project’s setup
>   directory if they’re not already installed locally.

http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html

If you have installed some package and you need to remove it,
just find your package in the subfolder "site-packages" of your python distribution 
and delete it. Finally remove the package reference in the easy-install.pth file
which is usually located in the same "site-packages" dir.

Comment: Thanks. Still what I was looking for was not to pollute my working copy when I run `setup.py`, which is in the root of the repository. So I I am looking for way of convincing setuptools to create these files somewhere else.

Comment: Corrected. I think you should go with a script!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with setuptools 7.0, transient dependencies loaded for `setup_requires`, `tests_require`, and similar are installed into ./.eggs. I strongly encourage adding that to your global ignore list.